# iOS Custom URL Schemes to open my other App with bundle identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to open my app with an identifier for example `com.mystorename.myfirstApp`

I'm trying to open it using the code below but can't open my application, my first app already install in iphone 7

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myfirstApp://"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
```

---

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>myfirstApp</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>com.mystorename.myfirstApp</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: you need app 1 to declare the scheme and app 2 to declare that it wants to use the url scheme (plist)

Comment: app 1 scheme and package added in plist or app 2

Comment: and trying to open app 1 on button press

Comment: you are just checking canOpenUrl but not calling openUrl, canOpenUrl will just return a boolean if it can open the specified url or not.